# Jquery show and hide elements according to position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a carousel of sorts. I am kind of stuck with hiding and displaying the next and precious buttons once a div moves to the far left and right of its container.

I think i have everything correct regarding calculating the widths but for some reason when you click the buttons, elements stay hidden irrespective of the conditional comments which should dictate when they should be hidden or shown.

Here is a link to what i have thus far. Click the MoveLeft and MoveRight buttons. http://www.ehbeat.com/test/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Check width of Gallery div
        var galleryWidth = $("#Gallery").innerWidth();

        //Check width of GalleryItem
        var galleryItemWidth = $(".GalleryItem").innerWidth();

        //Check distance from left
        var position = $('.GalleryItem').position();
        var galleryItemLeft = position.left;


        $(".MoveRight").click(function () {
            $(".GalleryItem").animate({
                "left": "+=50px"
            }, "slow");
            $(".GalleryItem2").animate({
                "left": "+=100px"
            }, "slow");
        });

        $(".MoveLeft").click(function () {
            $(".GalleryItem").animate({
                "left": "-=50px"
            }, "slow");
            $(".GalleryItem2").animate({
                "left": "-=100px"
            }, "slow");
        });

        $(".Controls").live('click', function () {
            if (galleryItemLeft >= "0") {
                $('.MoveRight').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('.MoveRight').show();
            }
        });

        if (galleryItemWidth == galleryWidth - galleryItemWidth) {
            $('.MoveLeft').hide();
        }


    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you setup all of your variables inside the **$(document).ready()** call.

This means that while they're being set on load, they're not getting updated with each click.

Your ***galleryItemLeft***, ***galleryItemWidth*** and ***galleryItemWidth*** variables need to be updated on each click, so I'd recommend re-assigning the values in each click (by moving the assignment into the live functions)

***Edit*** Also, as your last if statement is excluded from any click function, it'll need to be relocated to inside the live click events as well.

-Chris

Answer (score 0):

Chris is right, code should look like this:

```
$(".Controls").live('click', function() {
    position = $('.GalleryItem').position();
    galleryItemLeft = position.left;

    if(galleryItemLeft > "0") { 
        $('.MoveRight').hide();}
    else{
        $('.MoveRight').show();
    }

    if(galleryItemWidth == galleryWidth - galleryItemWidth) {
        $('.MoveLeft').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys that did the trick! My buttons are display one click after they should, any way to fix this? The buttons dont exactly hide or show according to my conditions and it makes it look kind of broken =/

http://www.ehbeat.com/test

Comment: It looks like the galleryItemLeft is being calculated before the animation occurred.

Comment: Salmon,  Are you trying to hide the MoveRight and MoveLeft buttons when the larger slideshow is not longer visible, or the smaller?